# Extracting Words in Sentence with Regex

Tags: regex, replace

I want to extract last two words of a sentence and replacing with other words. Let me describe by an example:

```
word1 word2 word3 word4 .... wordn-2 wordn-1 wordn
```

What I want is to replace this sentence with regex so I get sentence like this:

```
wordn-1 wordn : word1 word2 word3 word4 .... wordn-2
```

I tried

```
^(\w)* (\w)$
```

regex code to replace with

```
$2 : $1
```

but it is not working. Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(.*)\s+(\w+\s+\w+)$
```

will work with:

```
$2 : $1
```

For example, in JavaScript:

```
"word1 word2 word3 word4".replace(/^(.*)\s+(\w+\s+\w+)$/, "$2 : $1");
```

returns:

```
"word3 word4 : word1 word2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
^(.+)\b(\w+\s+\w+)$
```

Your regex will not match for several reasons:

- you repeat a captured group instead of capture a repeated group: `(\w)*` will have captured the last character of the word, you wanted to write `(\w*)` instead; and `(\w)` will not match a space character;
- what's more, you use the `*` quantifier instead of `+`: your first group could have been empty -- `*` means "zero or more";
- and finally, your second group, `(\w)`, only ever matches *one* word character.

Comment: I want to replace the first words except the last two words with the last two words. Your regex doesn't match as I intend.